# CCSpriteSheet random crash on draw

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am facing an issue in myApp that i am developing. I am using CCSpriteSheet for objects that move around the screen, the objects move randomly and after some time get removed from the screen. The crash usually occurs when the state is heavy when lots of objects are coming and removing, moreover it is completely random. I do not have any leaks in the code, the occurance is usually very less but increases when it first comes. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

I am using Cocos2d v 0.99.4/0.99.5rc0, Xcode SDK : 4.0/4.1

**CRASH:**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000004
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   IMGSGX535GLDriver                 0x0001f462 glrRenderVertexArray + 406
1   GLEngine                          0x0002c138 gleExecuteVertexArrayRange + 100
2   GLEngine                          0x0002db0a glDrawElements_ACC_Exec + 270
3   OpenGLES                          0x00003334 glDrawElements + 32
4   myApp                         0x000cfca6 -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads:] (CCTextureAtlas.m:306)
5   myApp                         0x000cf560 -[CCTextureAtlas drawQuads] (CCTextureAtlas.m:277)
6   myApp                         0x000cdb42 -[CCSpriteSheet draw] (CCSpriteSheet.m:291)
7   myApp                         0x000cd9ee -[CCSpriteSheet visit] (CCSpriteSheet.m:147)
8   myApp                         0x000b97c2 -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:486)
9   myApp                         0x00062e3c -[myAppGameLayer visit] (myAppGameLayer.m:38)
10  myApp                         0x000b97c2 -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:486)
11  myApp                         0x000a7c96 -[CCDirector drawScene] (CCDirector.m:253)
12  myApp                         0x000a673e -[CCDisplayLinkDirector preMainLoop:] (CCDirector.m:1212)
13  QuartzCore                        0x000926fc CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 144
14  QuartzCore                        0x00092820 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 44
15  IOMobileFramebuffer               0x00001bf4 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 68
16  ???                               0x35079040 0 + 889688128
17  CoreFoundation                    0x0003d30c __CFMachPortPerform + 204
18  CoreFoundation                    0x00034cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
19  CoreFoundation                    0x00034ca0 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
20  CoreFoundation                    0x00027566 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
21  CoreFoundation                    0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
22  CoreFoundation                    0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
23  GraphicsServices                  0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
24  GraphicsServices                  0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
25  UIKit                             0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
26  UIKit                             0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
27  myApp                         0x00002904 main (main.m:13)
28  myApp                         0x000028a8 start + 44
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are referencing an object that has been released.